# can't change hover color on image/icon

Tags: javascript, css

I created a circle icon and added an image in the center. I wan't the image to change colors on hover. The only real part of the icon is the circle. I have tried adding hover in the code for the circle icon like:

```
.circle-icon a:hover {
color: #0cf;
background-image:url(../images/phone-icon-blue-sm.png)}
```

So in the above I am attempting to swap out the image on hover and trying to change the color by adding a line to the style sheet. I am not sure that I can even do what I want without creating a rollover using javascript, which I am not thrilled about. The demo page is at:

```
http://tahoe-luxury-properties.com/index2.html
```

The icon that I am having trouble with is the phone link at the bottom right of the page. The facebook, linked in icons are working great. Just not my home made icon. I might have some code that I can use, but need to search that out. Any help, ideas are greatly appreciated. Thanks, Beth

Comment: `.circle-icon` is child of `a` element so you can't target it like this. Also you should set original image as css background, not in html like `<img>`

Comment: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].*

Answer (score 0):

You can't set a new img src via CSS.

Or you use two background's, or two img's tags (one hidded, that show on hover and hide the other).

```
/* hide second image, hide first on hover */
#social-icon-menu a em > img:last-child, #social-icon-menu a:hover em > img:first-child  {
     display: none; 
}

/* show second on hover */
#social-icon-menu a:hover em > img:last-child {
     display: block;
}
```

By the way, I noticed that your theme contains [FontAwesome](http://fontawesome.io/icons/), is much better using it, because it's a font icon, so you can just change his color, using color property via CSS.